# Magento admin product grid sorting is not working

Tags: magento-1.9

In my Magento site, admin product grid sorting is not working.

Sorting is happening only with price. Other than that with any of other columns, sorting is not working. I have not overwritten the core files related to this grid.

Can anyone give me a solution for this?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: please check in browser console for error , or check in your log files for possible error

Comment: i checked. there are no any errors displaying in both places. Is there any admin configuration to control grid sorting.

Comment: no I dont think so

Comment: Then do you have any idea why this is not working with columns except the price. Please help me :(

Comment: its very hard to find with seeing your package or code base

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons could be:

- Any third party module overrides core files possibly this file:`Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController`
- Try to unmerge JS files from `System > Configuration > Developer > Javascript Settings`